# Installing ubuntu with windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I already have windows 8 installed and wish to installed Ubuntu and continue using both windows 8 and Ubuntu. How do I install Ubuntu now?

Comment: Please review some the questions that have 'dual-boot' and 'windows-8' tags. *There are possible issues with Secure Boot, but try a test install (LiveCD) first and report on any issues.*