# Is there any way to install Ubuntu on NTFS ? Dual boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Is there any way to install Ubuntu on NTFS?

Because my files are in that drive, I wan't to dual boot between Win7 and XP.

Comment: You cant with dual boot. For Wubi see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation and http://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows

Comment: NTFS does not support the permission system as required by Ubuntu. You can choose to share the NTFS drive for data among all OS, but you will either have to install Ubuntu using wubi, which is not recommended if you would like to use Ubuntu seriously, or make a separate partition that meets the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is way is to install via WUBI, refer to [Installing ubuntu with windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227817/installing-ubuntu-with-windows-8/227824#227824)

Otherwise, it is possible for ubuntu to be installed on its own partition, while sparing your NTFS partition(as long as you have the space) and even access it from ubuntu if needed.

Comment: after opening ubuntu , ubuntu ask convert partation to ext4 :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to partition the disk in any case, so you may as well format the partition(s) for Ubuntu as normal (ext4 etc) and your NTFS data files will be accessible from within Ubuntu, but Windows won't see your Ubuntu data so you should consider where to store things that may need to be accessible from both i.e. put it on the NTFS (Windows) partition.

The installer will do the partitioning for you and give you dual boot if you choose the "Install alongside Windows" option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to install Ubuntu on NTFS ?

NTFS does not understand Linux permissions so that is a no.

> Alternative

It is fairly easy to create a new partition with a Windows program like Partition Magic that you then can use for Ubuntu. Just have to be careful when using it so you do not destroy any data.